# Non-rectified Voltage output across the capacitor

Tags: capacitor, oscilloscope, rectifier, voltage-measurement

So I am testing my PZT Piezoelectric material's Voltage output across a Capacitor of 1000uF after converting AC to DC using an Oscilloscope. Oscilloscope model: Gwinstek GDS-2102.

[image]

The diagram is my model for testing the Voltage across the capacitor.

I am trying to see the output across the capacitor when I tap the PZT. this follwing waveform is from my AC to DC converter.

[image]

So as you can see, my AC to DC works perfectly. But now the Voltage across the capacitor is shown in the next waveform.

[image]

So as you can see it is not a DC rectified waveform.

Could anyone please let me know what is going on here?

Comment: Scope set to AC coupling?

Comment: If you are trying to measure low voltage signals a diode bridge isn't ideal: the diodes drop 0.7 V when conducting, and there are always two of them in series with the load in a full wave rectifier. You wouldn't see anything at the output when the input signal is less than 1.4 V peak to peak.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Its the same with DC coupling ive checked it.

Comment: @jms I am using Schottky diode for this exact same reason and can clearly see an output there.

Comment: *Which* schottky diodes? Although they switch fast and drop just 0.2 V, they are known to have a significant reverse leakage current, sometimes many milliamps. Had you disclosed these details when asking the question, you could have had an answer faster.

Comment: Show us a screen capture with your scope set to DC coupling, because the ones you've posted look like they're AC coupled.

Comment: Why is the 2nd scope trace centred - is there a dc offset or have you adjusted the trace position?

Comment: @jms my ac to dc is working properly, so i dont think that reverse leakage would matter as i have very small current (uA) and mV. i am looking at why i have a negative value across the capacitor.

Comment: @brhans i have tested with DC coupling too and it is the same, i just forgot to change it afterwards before posting here.

Comment: @Andyaka i adjusted it for better reading in ac to dc

Comment: @imad The schottky reverse leakage matters *precisely because* the current is so small. The cap will discharge trough the diode bridge leakage, although it still shouldn't reach negative voltages unless some of the diodes are damaged. What schottky diodes are you using? Have you tested that all diodes work, scottkys tend to have a dramatically increased reverse leakage current when damaged by e.g. excessive reverse voltage or ESD.

Comment: @jms my diode is 1N5817 and yes i tested them across a DMM before soldering it to my circuitry. So are you stating that the negative part of my capacitor is due to the Schottky diode reverse leakage? if so, then please help me finding the solution to this.

Comment: The capacitor will discharge rather quickly via diode reverse leakage, but symmetric reverse leakage won't cause *negative* voltages in the capacitor. Negative voltages are most likely caused by a diode in your bridge that is broken and conducts both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Your capacitor is too large to allow the PZ to charge it. Try 1 uF or 0.01 uF.

Use 1N914 or 1N4148 diodes. If you use 1N4001-type, their leakage and parasitic capacitance may also degrade your output.

In any case, the scope input resistance will discharge the capacitor relatively quickly and the signal you get will actually be quite small.

Comment: 10MΩ from the probe is going to discharge the capacitor quickly? RC time constant is...